# How to encourage users with less than 3K rep to participate in tag burnination and cleanups?

Tags: discussion

It was occurring to me the other day: the primary manpower-intensive parts of burnination are editing tags and locating bad posts and putting them into the close vote queue and editing tags. You can edit tags at 2k reputation, flag bad posts at only 15 reputation, and cast binding downvotes at 125 reputation (to help make bad questions Roomba), meaning that most users who are even modestly active on the site can help with efforts in some way.

In particular, we have a large pool of users that can help identify and flag bad posts (unnecessary comments, VLQ answers, low quality and off-topic questions) to keep the review queues full - that's a *lot* of people that could potentially help.

That being the case, how can users with less than 3K reputation be encouraged to participate in tag cleanup and burnination?

Comment: *'the primary manpower-intensive parts of burnination are locating bad posts"* Uh, can't really see how. They're all the ones with the tag being burninated. A simple tag search finds 'em all.

Comment: How do you encourage *anyone* to participate in tag burnination and cleanups?  It's not just that group; it's most everyone that *can*.

Comment: @CodyGray I disagree - it's rarely the case that even a relatively bad tag will consists entirely of bad posts, so you still need to manually sort through them to identify which ones to close and which ones you should just edit.

Comment: Have you considered that some people really don't care about tag burninations? It's one of the most menial tasks you can perform, with the smallest gains, while pushing old, irrelevant posts to the homepage.

Comment: Given how often this goes horribly wrong, the only sensible demand is for participants to have *more* than the required rep.  Well, that's not going to happen either.

Comment: @CodeCaster If done right (which it rarely is), no questions are needlessly bumped to the homepage. The point is to _not_ edit questions that only need the tag edited, then close and delete off-topic questions and edit questions that could use some editing otherwise. Once your done closing and deleting, a CM can come along and batch remove the tag from all remaining questions without bumping any of them. This puts even more light toward the fact that users with less than 3k cannot do very much, other than editing the posts that could otherwise use some editing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I don't think users with less than 2k reputation *should* be participating in tag burninations.**

Two reasons why not:

1. Philosophically, at less than 2k reputation, you are probably not sufficiently qualified to make independent judgments about how to make good edits, which questions are off-topic, and generally how to handle borderline cases. There's a reason that the site doesn't grant editing or close-vote privileges until you reach this reputation level. Up until this point, you are essentially still riding with training wheels.
2. Pragmatically, with less than 2k reputation, there isn't much that you can actually do to help in a burnination. Everything that you *can* do would mostly just be creating more work for others who do have the requisite privileges. You can throw posts into a queue, but that doesn't help because *finding* questions that need attention is not the hard part—it's actually *giving* those questions the attention they require.

At <2k, all you can do is suggest edits, which just makes more work for everyone. Now, at least two 2k+ users have to review and approve your edits, which is a less effective use of their time than each of them independently making edits to two questions.

**If you have more than 2k, but less than 3k, reputation, then you can make edits to and retag questions as part of the burnination process.** For questions that need to be closed, you can flag (and skip editing). So, I don't have a problem with such users participating in burnination procedures. That said, I'm not really sure how many users fall into this privilege window and aren't currently participating but would be interested in doing so.

Comment: The question focuses around < 3K users, but I am assuming an implied 2K <= x < 3K reputation boundary here...

Comment: That's the last paragraph. I missed bolding it originally. (-1 needs moar bold)

Answer (score 4):

It's all a grind. In terms of decreasing reward, not necessarily talking about reputation, I identify the following activities when using the site:

1. Trolling the frontpage, finding posts to close, edit or answer, in that order. I wish it were the other way around.
2. Going back to posts I voted or commented on to see if something has changed.
3. Going through the review queues to see if there's anything fun to do.
4. Going to Meta to see if there's any drama to read or answer.

Notice how participating in tag burninations didn't even make that list? It's because it's boring as hell, while I also highly doubt its usefulness. When removing tags, you're giving old, usually off-topic or low-quality posts attention they don't deserve. You're also pushing them to the frontpage by editing them, causing even more people to look at them.

So I don't think the question should be *"How to get relatively low-rep users interested in burninations"*, but *"How to get *anyone* interested in burninations?"*. Perhaps try convincing people of their usefulness.